# How to reference a variable within a variable in VSTS vNext build definition?

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

How is it possible to reference a variable within a variable in the new scripting system of VSTS?

e.g:

RemoteMachineFqdn: somemachinename.somedomain

RemoteMachineUncPath: \\$(RemoteMachineFqdn)\c$\

In the aforementioned example, assume there are tasks that both use CMD and Powershell scripts with the given variables. I tried using the the variables by referencing their values from the environment but it does not work for both scenarios since %variable% works only in CMD and $env:variable - only in Powershell.

What is the standard way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md). To invoke a logging command, simply emit the command via standard output. For example, from a PowerShell task:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
```

This example sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.