# Devops Yaml getting value of variable inside another variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

In Azure devops I want to use a variable inside a task but I want the contents of the variable rather than the name itself, so it's an extra level of indirection.

```
somecommand --value `"$(MyVariable)`"
```

MyVariable ultimately comes from a Variable group set up in devops and listed in the variables section at the top of the file.

So if I had a variable MyVariable="foo" and another my variable group had a member foo="bar" would expect this to be the outcome.

somecommand --value "bar"

How do I do this extra level of indirection?

Comment: Are you using Bash to execute `somecommand`?  If so, you can do `somecommand --value "${!MyVariable}"`.

Comment: I'm just using Azure Devops I don't know what that uses under the hood

Comment: For now, the nested variable like `$($(MyVariable))=>$(foo)=>bar` is not supported in azure devops task, an alternative way to do that is set your variable `MyVariable`=`$(foo)` instead of `foo`... We can also use inline PS task to do that like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215166/10910450) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113070/10910450).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do this extra level of indirection?

If you have `foo = bar` in Variable Group and `MyVariable = foo` in pipeline variables, VSTS doesn't support **nested variables** like `$($(MyVariable))` even after we've [linked Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-variable-group).

To make your `somecommand --value "$(MyVariable)"` expand to `somecommand --value "bar"`, you should set `MyVariable = $(foo)` instead of `foo` in pipeline variables.

[image]

In this way the `$(MyVariable)` could be expanded to `bar` when being passed to your command.

And another alternative way is to use Inline Powershell task to set the variable.You may get some help from these two similar issues([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215166/10910450), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113070/10910450)).